# Using EntityFieldQuery's FieldCondition on file fields (or complex fields)

Tags: files, database

I see plenty of examples of using FieldCondition on basic fields but in my case I would like to query if the file field holds a specific file name.

The structure in the entity object (with language undefined) is:

```
$entity->field_file['und'][0]['filename']
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', $type)
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_file', 'filename', $tokens[1], '=')
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

$result = $query->execute();
```

Perhaps it is having trouble because of the ['und'][0] not sure? Thanks.

Here is the detailed error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_data_field_file0.field_file_filename' in 'where clause': SELECT field_data_field_file0.entity_type AS entity_type, field_data_field_file0.entity_id AS entity_id, field_data_field_file0.revision_id AS revision_id, field_data_field_file0.bundle AS bundle FROM {field_data_field_file} field_data_field_file0 INNER JOIN {eck_downloadable} eck_downloadable ON eck_downloadable.id = field_data_field_file0.entity_id WHERE (field_data_field_file0.field_file_filename = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (field_data_field_file0.deleted = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (eck_downloadable.status = :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND (field_data_field_file0.entity_type = :db_condition_placeholder_3) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => rnd13_poster_pack.pdf [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => downloadable ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_query() (line 582 of C:\www\sr14\modules\field\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file field only contains the `fid` (file ID) relating to the file. The extra data you see (filename, uri, etc.) are loaded by the file module, but are actually contained in the `file_managed` table, which is not a field table.

Since `EntityFieldQuery` doesn't support `JOIN`s you're out of luck, unless you alter the query a bit later on, e.g.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->addTag('customtag');

...

function MYMODULE_query_customtag_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->innerJoin('file_managed', 'file_managed', 'file_managed.fid = field_data_field_name.fid');
  $query->condition('file_managed.filename', $something);
}
```

That will obviously need some tweaking for your specific situation.